# Bash, using expect keyword

Tags: bash, playonlinux, expect

I have connected to a port like this:

```
nc hello-world.mygame.com 2000
```

which opens a small game like this:

```
Please enter your name
a
hello a,
```

Now I know that a specific number of repeated "a" 's will give special output, how can I iterate over them easily (a then aa then aaa and so on) to get to that special output?

**My first try:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1; i<=30; i++){s=s "a"; print s}}' | nc hello-world.mygame.com 2000
```

But it only submits `a` as input, how can I let it wait for others? I don't know how to use `expect` here?

**My second try:**

```
for x in a aa aaa; do echo $x | nc hello-world.mine.com 2000 done
```

Comment: It shows the following and end: Please enter your name:
Thanks, a
 Have a nice day!

Comment: expect_autoexpect can help you with creating a expect script.